# Can't accesses class variables

Tags: c++, class, variables, header

Hello I'm new to C++ and headers, and I can't figure out how to get a variable I declare in the header.

MyClass.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    int numberOfJellyBeans;
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
    void GenerateJellyBeans();
}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    //constructor
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    //destructor
}
void GenerateJellyBeans()
{
    //doesnt work?
    numberOfJellyBeans = 250;

    //Also doesnt work
    MyClass::numberOfJellyBeans = 250;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GenerateJellyBeans()` has to be in the scope of `MyClass`, so you have to write:

```
void MyClass::GenerateJellyBeans()
{

  numberOfJellyBeans = 250;
}
```

Now C++ knows that `GenerateJellyBeans()` is member of `MyClass`, you can access the variables of your class now.

If you just declare it plain `void GenerateJellyBeans()`, there is no `this` for the compiler to work with (actually `numberOfJellyBeans = 250;` is shorthand for `this->numberOfJellyBeans = 250;` )

Answer (score 1):

You are accidentally defining a free function called `GenerateJellyBeans` that's unrelated to `MyClass::GenerateJellyBeans`. To correct this:

```
void MyClass::GenerateJellyBeans()
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Now you'll be able to access `numberOfJellyBeans`:

```
{
    numberOfJellyBeans = 250;
}
```

Comment: Thank you i just realized i forgot to update my header after i added some parameters when i tried doing that before.